# Chrome Instances don't close after running Test Case in Protractor

Tags: google-chrome, automation, protractor

When I run the test multiple times so Chrome instances do not close due to which PC utilization tends to 100%. So, I have to end Chrome instances manually. There might be some way to handle this?

Solution :

```
chromeOptions: {
  args: ["--disable-gpu"]
},
```

In Configuration file "Disable-gpu" is responsible to disable acceleration of chrome whenever there is some problem in rendering(in-case of failure).

Comment: Are you using the "restartBrowserBetweenTests: true" flag in your conf file?

Comment: Please share your protractor.config.

Comment: chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--disable-gpu"]
    } is responsible for closing Chrome instances. In my configuration file I have added this argument that disable acceleration whenever problem comes in rendering.

Answer (score 0):

By default protractor closes chrome instances after test execution unless the test fails in an irreconcilable way. So try to reset your protractor.conf.js settings back to default

Comment: yes I have added chromeOptions: { args: ["--disable-gpu"] } in my configuration due to which chrome instances started to get closed itself.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that has worked for everybody in our company was removing `"--no-sandbox"` argument from config file from the line that looked like this

```
chromeOptionsArgs = ["incognito", "--window-size=1920,1080", "disable-extensions", "start-maximized", "--no-sandbox", "--test-type=browser"];
```