# Protractor: Can only enable virtual time for pages, not workers

Tags: angular, protractor, chromium

In my angular app, I have outsourced some of the heavy logic to a Web Worker.
After running the e2e tests using protractor in Chrome Headless, I get the error below on every action protractor is making. Note that the e2e results are still good. Only this annoying error log.

```
[1003/234747.472:ERROR:inspector_emulation_agent.cc(537)] Can only enable virtual time for pages, not workers
```

Someone already seen this?

The error it self is coming from Chromium

```
Response InspectorEmulationAgent::AssertPage() {
  if (!web_local_frame_) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Can only enable virtual time for pages, not workers";
    return Response::InvalidParams(
      "Can only enable virtual time for pages, not workers");
  }
  return Response::OK();
}
```

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/master/blink/renderer/core/inspector/inspector_emulation_agent.cc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your configuration file, there is `capabilities` object (or `multiCapabilities` if you run your tests against multiple browsers). This object, among other things, has a property `args` which takes array of arguments

```
capabilities: {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "chromeOptions": {
        "args": ["incognito","--window-size=1920,1080","disable-extensions","--no-sandbox","start-maximized","--test-type=browser"]
    }
}
```

Remove `"--no-sandbox"` argument!

What this guy does is it allows your tests to be ran from a remote container (i.e. in Jenkins). In the meantime, if you include the argument when you run your tests on your machine, it has side effects like described here [Chrome Instances don't close after running Test Case in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876063/chrome-instances-dont-close-after-running-test-case-in-protractor/50532932#50532932)

---

I assume it causes your errors as well. So "Can only enable virtual time..." probably indicates that there is no "virtual" container and only local process.

My temporary solution of the problem was to always remove this argument from my local config, but not to commit it.

My permanent solution was to create an optional flag `isHost` through Grunt with a default value `false`. Then in my config if the parameter is `true` I push `"--no-sandbox"` on top of others chrome arguments. And when I configured CI I start Protractor with that argument

Comment: Nice! This indeed is working properly.
I still need the `--no-sandbox` flag on the CI environment, but I can live with that
cheers

Comment: Yeah, what I do I always remove this argument from my local config, but don't commit it. In this way CI still sees it. Glad it helped