# ERROR:inspector_emulator_agent.cc(477) Can only enable virtual time for pages, not workers while test execution through Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been using Selenium with Python (and Chrome, with chromedriver) to successfully automate interacting with a website, but recently my script has stopped working.

I've narrowed it down to one line that the script gets to but then no further--and then nothing else ever occurs. No error is given, no matter how long I wait. The script just hangs there.

The line is this:

```
start_text_area = driver.find_element_by_id('startDate')
```

After some searching, I thought the situation might be helped if I tried using a timeout, so I tried this code:

```
 try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "startDate"))
        )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

But that had the same result: Nothing happened, though I waited for a while.

As I said, this was working until very recently. I am not aware if the website I used changed.

I should also mention that when I launch the website, I also get a terminal window and I see there is an error message for chromedriver in that. That error message is this:

```
[1022/123519.xxx:ERROR:inspector_emulator_agent.cc(477)] Can only enable virtual time for pages, not workers
```

Any idea what might cause this, or what I could do about it?

Comment: Which action with the WebElement `element` makes you feel nothing happens? Can you update the question with the error stack trace?

Comment: @DebanjanB There is no error within Python. It just never executes the next line of code (which is a print, just to test whether it gets there).

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
[1022/123519.xxx:ERROR:inspector_emulator_agent.cc(477)] Can only enable virtual time for pages, not workers
```

...is the `Response` from `InspectorEmulationAgent::AssertPage()` used by *Chrome Driver* and *Chrome* / *Chromium*.

The function is defined in [inspector_emulation_agent.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/master/blink/renderer/core/inspector/inspector_emulation_agent.cc) as:

```
Response InspectorEmulationAgent::AssertPage() {
  if (!web_local_frame_) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Can only enable virtual time for pages, not workers";
    return Response::InvalidParams(
    "Can only enable virtual time for pages, not workers");
  }
  return Response::OK();
```

This error is observed when you use the argument **`--no-sandbox`** through an instance of `ChromeOptions()` as follows:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
```

### Solution

- Removing the the argument **`--no-sandbox`** will solve the issue.
- If you are on *Windows OS* you need to add the argument **`--disable-gpu`** as follows:

  ```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  ```

### References

- [Chrome Instances don't close after running Test Case in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876063/chrome-instances-dont-close-after-running-test-case-in-protractor)

Comment: Thanks. But I don't use webdriver.ChromeOptions() in my Python script. Do think the line is in the chromedriver module?

Comment: @Chelonian Of-coarse yes, else how do you maximize _Chrome Browser_ window?

Comment: Sorry, I can't recall if I downvoted, but I don't think that was my intention, as I appreciated the answer. I have upvoted it now. Also, do you think this error would interact with the problem of the script hanging on the find_element_by_id line? (In any case, my script does work if I use geckodriver and Firefox).