# Protractor test fails on CI

Tags: protractor

Currently I am trying a  setup an end to end protractor tests to a a bitbucket pipelines with set up an headless chrome and i am currently getting some error message:

Failed: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used. 
Any clue for this? how ever running tests locally is working fine; Can i set a constant session id? 
Thanks

Comment: couldn't fit in the comment, so posted as an answer. If doesn't help post your config file, we'll go from there

Answer (score 1):

Check out your configuration file for this object

```
capabilities: {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions": {
            "args": ["incognito", "--window-size=1920,1080", "disable-extensions", "--no-sandbox", "start-maximized", "--test-type=browser"],
            "prefs": {
                "download": {
                    "prompt_for_download": false,
                    "directory_upgrade": true,
                    "default_directory": path.join(process.cwd(), "__test__reports/downloads")
                    }
                }
        }
    },
```

When you find it, make sure you included `"--no-sandbox"` argument into `args` property.

What this guy does is it allows your tests to be ran from a remote container. In the meantime, if you include the argument when you run your tests on your machine, it has side effects like described here [Chrome Instances don't close after running Test Case in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876063/chrome-instances-dont-close-after-running-test-case-in-protractor/50532932#50532932)

Comment: thanks for  heads-up, yes this was helped a lot to fill-out the  session issues  and also I had to assign a variable to the page objects /each page and clear the sessions on each tests before and after  then problem was solved