# Protractor constantly running out of memory

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium, protractor

I am working with protractor tests and recently encountered memory related issue - javascript heap out of memory. I tried increasing memory heap via `--max-old-space-size=8096` but even though one node instance has ~8GB of memory it is still able to reach that limit and crash. I implemented some kind of memory tracker and put

`` console.log('login memory data', ` ${heap} MB ${'\t'}| ${diffHeap} MB ${'\t'}`) `` and

`` console.log('logout memory data', ` ${heap} MB ${'\t'}| ${diffHeap} MB ${'\t'}`) ``

inside my login/logout class (which is used in every test); this gave me very interesting results:

> login memory data  2369.92 MB  | 0.00 MB

on login and

> logout memory data 2492.42 MB  | 122.50 MB

on logout

the last data ( test before getting the javascript heap out of memory ) "ate" a huge amount of memory:

> logout memory data 4706.79 MB     | 1608.02 MB

and then the message:

```
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6777685Z [chrome #01] FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6777832Z [chrome #01]  1: 00007FF6981DF04A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+5114
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6777974Z [chrome #01]  2: 00007FF6981BA0C6 node::MakeCallback+4518
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6778090Z [chrome #01]  3: 00007FF6981BAA30 node_module_register+2032
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6778211Z [chrome #01]  4: 00007FF6984420EE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6778349Z [chrome #01]  5: 00007FF69844201F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6778558Z [chrome #01]  6: 00007FF698962BC4 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9556
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6778688Z [chrome #01]  7: 00007FF698959C46 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24310
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6778826Z [chrome #01]  8: 00007FF69895829C v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17740
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6778951Z [chrome #01]  9: 00007FF69895E1B7 v8::internal::Heap::CreateFillerObjectAt+1175
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6779142Z [chrome #01] 10: 00007FF6987EC5B3 v8::internal::interpreter::Interpreter::GetDispatchCountersObject+78451
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6779294Z [chrome #01] 11: 00007FF698141132 v8::internal::StackGuard::ArchiveSpacePerThread+52082
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6779428Z [chrome #01] 12: 00007FF6981417F3 v8::internal::StackGuard::ArchiveSpacePerThread+53811
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6779624Z [chrome #01] 13: 00007FF698221474 uv_dlerror+2436
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6779757Z [chrome #01] 14: 00007FF6982221D8 uv_run+232
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6779869Z [chrome #01] 15: 00007FF6981C128E node::NewContext+1390
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6779994Z [chrome #01] 16: 00007FF6981C189B node::NewIsolate+603
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6780105Z [chrome #01] 17: 00007FF6981C1D07 node::Start+839
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6780243Z [chrome #01] 18: 00007FF69807935C node::MultiIsolatePlatform::MultiIsolatePlatform+604
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6780377Z [chrome #01] 19: 00007FF698C1A93C v8::internal::compiler::OperationTyper::ToBoolean+134796
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6780506Z [chrome #01] 20: 00007FFC34C484D4 BaseThreadInitThunk+20
2020-02-05T14:21:13.6780635Z [chrome #01] 21: 00007FFC35F4E8B1 RtlUserThreadStart+33
```

This lead me to a conclusion that between each spec memory is not being released.
I run these tests on two environments and on second one the tests are passing however protractor still uses a lot ( ~2,5GB ) of memory for them.

What are possible causes of such huge memory consumption? I may add that test are heavily based on `browser.wait`

Here is my conf.js file

````
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

var browserToken = '#{browser}#';
var _browserName = browserToken.replace(/\W/g, '') === 'browser' ? 'chrome' : browserToken;
exports.config = {
  params: {
// config stuff
  },
  directConnect: true,
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.params.url = `${browser.params.protocol}://${browser.params.address}`;
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
// config stuff   
    }).getJasmine2Reporter());
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec: {
        displayStacktrace: true
      }
    }));

    return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
      var browserName = config.capabilities.browserName;
      var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({{
`${generatedSuiteName}.${browser.params.environmentName}.${browserName}`;
          }
      });
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
    });


  },

  onComplete: function(){
    browser.driver.close().then(function(){
      browser.driver.quit();
    });
  },
  multiCapabilities: [
    {         
      'browserName': _browserName,
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--window-size=3840,2160", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--ignore-ssl-errors",  "--headless"]
      },
      specs: [    
      ], 
    },

    {         
      'browserName': _browserName,
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--window-size=3840,2160", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--ignore-ssl-errors",  "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox" ]
      },
      specs: [    
       ], 
    },
    {        
      'browserName': _browserName,
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--window-size=3840,2160", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--ignore-ssl-errors", "--headless"]
      },
      specs: [    
      ], 
    },
  ],
  }
};```
````

Comment: are you on Windows machine?

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov that is correct - to be precise tests are running remotely via Microsoft Team Foundation Server

Comment: but the remote machine where you run them is linux or windows?

Comment: anyways try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50532932/9150146

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov i included my config file for more information on the problem. Tried the `--no-sandbox` flag but didn't help much. Tried splitting multicapabilities into each single conf file and run them as separate "task" in Team Foundation Server but this also gave the same memory error as before. Any ideas?

Remote machine is ofc Windows